# How can I change text object on the fly (RaphaelJS)?

Tags: text, raphael

Lets' say I have following text object:
        var text = r.print(50, 50, "demo", r.getFont("Impact", 50), 30).attr({fill: '#fff', stroke: '#000'});

And later want to change it on mouse event to "something".

How can I do that?
text.attr('text', 'something') doesn't work, nor text[0].attr['text'], 's')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for...

```
text.attr({'text': 'something'})
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/EUrQv/

Answer (score 0):

[Paper.print()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.print) is not that same as [Paper.text()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.text). As far as I can tell, it's possible to change the text of the latter, but not the former (as print converts the text into a series of paths).